# application/ld+json and javascript data exchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, json-ld

I have some jQuery code which constructs an array called `myList[]`. This array appears in the console like this: `["2 items", "3items", "so on"]`, so this part goes well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myList = [];
function buld myList(){
...
}
```

I need to pass `myList[]` to the `application/ld+json` like

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Recipe",
    "recipeIngredients": myList, //this one doesn't work 
}
```

..

How can I pass the values from javascript to the `application/ld+json`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to place `ld+json` markup on your page then do it on server side. Google doesn't read maskup created on client side.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Yes google detect client side created markups :D

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Can you give a prooflink?

Comment: Here you go [link](https://gistcdn.githack.com/iRbouh/674c58801268a07ecc5b48d9beb5078f/raw/a5fdaaa84b37039ab5e3a8cdf967a3299e28c3fd/json-ld-dynamic-markup.html) and the [test tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) . Welcome to 2016 :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<script id="myJSONID" type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

Then:

```
var myList = [];

function buildMyList() {
    return ["2 items", "3items", "so on"];
}

$("#myJSONID").text(function() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "recipeIngredient": buildMyList()
    });
});
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myList = [];    
  function buildMyList() {
      return ["2 items", "3items", "so on"];
  }

  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.type = 'application/ld+json';

  el.text = JSON.stringify({
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "recipeIngredient": buildMyList()
    });

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el);
</script>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/9po7dtg4/

**Note:** Please make sure you change `recipeIngredients` to `recipeIngredient`, singular. (Thank you @AlexKudryashev).

Comment: Sorry this one doesn;t work either. This is the rich card snippets of google. when I try to run the test on their testing tool it stumbles at the "var" (of var myList = [] ) Google concerns it to be a syntax mistake...

Comment: The property is `recipeIngredient` which can be text or array of strings. http://schema.org/Recipe

Comment: The last one has worked out! Thanks guys! @Ismail RBOUH, you've made my day!