# On AEM JSP page pass value of <script type="text/javascript"> to <script type="application/ld+json">

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, jstl, aem

I am working on an AEM component head.jsp component.
What I need is to grab the value I got in `<script type="text/javascript">` to display in `<script type="application/ld+json">` for head in final generated html
Below is my code try out:

```
<c:if test="<%= isHomePage %>">
    <cq:include script="includes/head/homepageData.html" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var homePageUri = window.location.pathname;
        alert(homePageUri);
    </script>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "WebSite",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/" + homePageUri,
          "potentialAction": [{
            "@type": "SearchAction",
            "target": "https://www.example.com" + homePageUri + "cat/?ft={search_name_str}",
            "query-input": "required name=search_name_str"
          }]
        }
    </script>
 </c:if>
```

I can confirm `alert(homePageUri)` this part works, say it got the homePageUri value is /GB/en/ , so in `<script type="application/ld+json">`  I wish to append this value to url and target,  so it becomes https://www.example.com/GB/en,  but currently it shows on html as `"url": "https://www.selfridges.com" + homePageUri,`  which is definitely something went wrong or I missed anything, could someone point out please (some code example would be very helpful)
Thanks

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557342/10606400) answer? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437546/application-ldjson-and-javascript-data-exchange) post ?

Answer (score 0):

This script element

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "url": "https://www.example.com/" + homePageUri,
      "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "https://www.example.com" + homePageUri + "cat/?ft={search_name_str}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_name_str"
      }]
    }
</script>
```

*isn't recognised by the browser as executable JavaScript*, and rightly so. It's not a piece of JavaScript, it's a JSON document that's meant to be rendered at the back-end.

The JSP is evaluated on the server side and it prints the contents of your JSON LD script verbatim.

Then, once the page has loaded in the browser, the JS kicks in and evaluates the first script element but not the second one (because it's not JavaScript).

What you should do here is print the URL at the server-side. Also, you shouldn't have to hardcode the domain anywhere like this. It needs to come from a [Sling mapping](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html).

Consider encapsulating the generation of the whole JSON document in a Sling Model and printing it inside the `script` element. That way you'll be able to unit-test it quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="application/ld+json">` isn't processed as javascript, it is just a JSON block. You can use JSP variables to insert your content there, i.e.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "url": "https://www.example.com<%= currentPage.getPath() %>",
      "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "https://www.example.com<%= currentPage.getPath() %>/cat/?ft={search_name_str}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_name_str"
      }]
    }
</script>
```